# DOMException: Could not start video source android

Tags: android, angular, twilio, getusermedia, domexception

I am using Twilio Service to implement video chat.
But I faced on this error.

> DOMException: Could not start video source android

My code like as bellow.

```
var options = {};
var _this = this;

var browser = <any>navigator;

browser.getUserMedia = (browser.getUserMedia ||
  browser.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  browser.mozGetUserMedia ||
  browser.msGetUserMedia);

browser.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(devices => {
    options = {
      video: {},
      audio: false
    }
    var isAudioInput = false;
    var isAudioOutput = false;
    devices.forEach(device => {
      if (device.kind === "videoinput") {
        var width = document.getElementById('main_participant').clientWidth;
        var height = document.getElementById('main_participant').clientHeight;
        options['video'] = { width, height };
      } else if (device.kind === 'audioinput') {
        isAudioInput = true;
      } else if (device.kind === 'audiooutput') {
        isAudioOutput = true;
      }
    })
    if (isAudioInput && isAudioOutput) {
      options['audio'] = true;
    }
    _this.createLocalMediaTracks(room.data, options); // This part is for create Twilio Room
  });

createLocalMediaTracks(room, options) {
  // Set Initial Device Status and set current status
  this.audioStatus = options.audio;
  this.videoStatus = options.video ? true : false;
  this.initialStatus = options;

  // Create Local Tracks with Device Status
  createLocalTracks(options)
    .then(localTracks => {
      return connect(room.accessToken, {
        name: room.roomName,
        tracks: localTracks
      })
    }).then(room => {
      this.room = room;
      // Add LocalMediaTrack
      this.participants.push("You");
      this.room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
        if (this.mainParticipant.index === 0) { 
 document.getElementById(`main_participant`).appendChild(publication.track.attach());
          this.setFullSize("#main_participant video", true);
        }
        document.getElementById(`local-media`).appendChild(publication.track.attach());
        this.setFullSize("#local-media video");
      })
      this.handleListen();
      this.loading = false;
    })
}
```

This code works well on web platform.
But doesn't work on mobile platform.
I tested it about on my mobile, and also on android emulator (Nox App Player).

Now I am developing this video call with **ANGULAR** and no ionic based.

Comment: How are you embedding this as an Android app with Angular if you are not using ionic? What is the `browser` object in your example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I want to say is, I am not developing an app, just a website that includes video chat. And the browser object is Android/Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `browser = <any>navigator` at the top there. What is `_this.createLocalMediaTracks`? It's not a function from Twilio Video that I can find. Can you include that implementation?

Comment: I've added the createLocalMediaTracks Function. Please check.

Comment: You're trying to set the height and width of the video based on an element on the page. Have you tried just setting `video: true` in the `createLocalTracks` options? Just to see if that makes it work?

Comment: Yup, I did that. Just with video: true, but the result was the same.

Comment: What happens if you cut things down to just the basics? Just run `createLocalTracks({ video: true, audio: true })` with none of the rest of the code? Does it still not work? Have you tried turning your device off and on again?

Comment: For what it's worth, `enumerateDevices()` on android is going to come up with two or maybe three video devices (front, back, telephoto, etc).

Comment: I've run only createLocalTracks({video: true, audio: true}), but it also has got same issue.